# Why do we use -i in Linux commands?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

Why do we use -i in linux commands and what is it's use?
e.g.
ssh -i .\filename.pem root@192.168.43.4
(or)
sudo -i
What's the use of -i here?

Comment: There's no single answer. It depends on the command itself. Read the manual pages to find out what that option does for each command. [ssh manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) and [sudo manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For different commands, there can be different parameter options and `i` can be one of them.

By checking the help you can understand the meaning of each of them. This can be done by

- `man command` -> will show the manual page of the command

or

- `command -h` or `command --help` -> will show the help page

Try with `sudo` instead of `command`, you will understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

ssh -i identity_file A file from which the identity key (private key) for public key authentication is read.

sudo -i -(simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell. The security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs in. The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.